# Software License For Proprietary Software Open Only For Licensee Modification and Security Review?

Tags: software, open-source-software

I'm looking for a software license (calling it "open source" would be incorrect) which can be loosely modified to meet the following objectives:

- Maintains the ability to sell seats to software for the original creator of the software granting things like number of servers, cores, users, featuresets, etc.
- Maintains the ability of the original creator to license, sell or otherwise distribute in any manner they please.
- Available to download for modification and use by the person/corporation modifying it with the licensed seats unable to change (a modified version counts the same as an unmodified version for the purpose of licensed seats and must adhere to the underlying license itself.)
- No rights to redistribute in a modified form for sale or otherwise unless the licensee is licensed for that specific purpose.
- Maintains patent and trademark rights for the original creator of the software while granting their use implicitly for however many seats the licensee has.

The purpose of this would be to have proprietary software which is open source both for security (lots of cryptographic tools involved and that stuff is just wrong to keep closed source) and for modification by the licensee (so they can add/remove functions for their specific environment without waiting on support if they so choose, compile from source to avoid working with binaries, etc.)

This would be coupled with implicit licenses for something like 100 servers per individual for non-commercial use, 10 per individual for commercial and 1,000 for a non profit organization.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to write the license for you? That's asking for legal advice, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Not even remotely, I'm asking if anyone knows of one.

Answer (score 2):

If you own the copyright you can do any and all if this. You can draft the licence yourself but you will need a lawyer to make it watertight.